range structure naming in modern C++ (since potential name conflict with std::ranges::range)
Having lots of code in C++ which deals with intervals of values this way or another, I found handy to have a structure that contains extents for the diapasons I am dealing with.
So, many years I've been having the template range which holds min and max and provides some basic operations for them, like here:
template <typename T = float>
struct range {
    T min, max;

    void update(T value) {
        min = std::min(min,value);
        max = std::max(max,value);
    }

    T center() const {
        return (min + max) / 2;
    }
};

template <typename T>
T clamp(T value, range<T> range) {
    return std::clamp(value, range.min, range.max);
}

It is very handy to store any bounds for values and function calls like:
range<std::size_t> frequiencies_range = { 0, std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() };

range<> values_range = { std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<float>::max() };

float random(const range<float>& r);
int random(const range<int>& r);
size_t random(const range<size_t>& r);

I'm particularly concerned whether the name I have used is clear. I've considered many different words for the same thing (interval, extents, diapasons). I don't like “range” since it could cause a great confusion in modern C++ since std::range is now almost a term. Meanwhile I can still use “bounds” and many other synonyms.
I've always called it range (with the small ‘r’ as many std classes and templates) - but now many developers say that they are confused with this name because of its close similarity to std::ranges library, especially when it comes to discussion about code and I say that something is represented as “range” and they assume that I talk about std::ranges::range. So, it looks to be a good time to move into calmer uncharted waters to avoid confusions.
Taking into account current state of C++, its standard libraries, current plans of language development (on terms), your experience, what would be your advice for naming of this structure?
Here are some points why I don’t like some specific names on my initial list:

interval – long name, I will use it often and don’t like my code to be long.
diapason – even longer and additionally the spelling is hard for some people and they tend to misspell.
extents, bounds – still long and can be confused with geometrical properties often used in CAD/CAM and game development; so, I want my own be used more generically than to specify extents/bounds of some objects in 2D/3D.

Are there any good ideas for concise and informative naming which wouldn’t come into conflict with new language generations (at least as we foresee it)? Maybe something widely used now in libraries, by community, etc.? Some kind of de facto standard or adherence?

@TobySpeight, thank you, it keeps my original question, so no any objections from my side. My focus here is to make sure that I've not missed some obvious name which is widely used in industry by C/C++ developers and became de facto standard for this. I would be curious if nobody uses the same structure, as well.

It’s an interval. That is the correct mathematical name. “Range” is not (if the interval is [-3,4], the range would be 7). Even if it were, there would be nothing wrong with using it. There are a ton of geometry libraries that define vector types, with no problem, and I don’t doubt there are many container, view, and stream classes out there. That’s what namespaces are for.

@indi, I see. Would the interval have a shorter nickname like int (joking here), I would be happy. Why this couldn't be bounds or extents? Still long, but what wrong with them? And... my problem is not with namespaces and language itself, my problem is with communication with other developers. When they hear range that think about std::ranges::range; when they see in code range they assume I am crazy enough to write somewhere in header file using namespace std::ranges;.

Defining a set of bounds or extents, or a range of values, are ways that an interval could be used… but an interval is what it is. (And if you’re concerned about name clashes… well….) This is a pretty universal name. If the “other developers” you are trying to communicate with are not capable of understanding that the same word can mean different things in different contexts, then I’d say you have a much bigger problem than naming a type.

@indi, thanks for the links, it helps. On the "interval" only the length now is my concern, since the type name will force at some degree the variables names (which usually follows the type consciously or unconsciously ) and which makes lines of code longer which in math calculations matters (formulas long themselves). As for "other developers" here is the recent quote "The range here drives me mad, since range is a well-known term in C++ word like vector and I assume this way of usage". So they are fine with other vectors, they are surprised when range is totally different thing.

Curious how the “other developers” can tell a mathematical vector and std::vector are “totally different” yet are completely lost to the distinction between a mathematical range and std::ranges::range. Also… the length of the word “interval” is a concern? Seriously? 1) It’s literally just 3 chars longer than “range”; 2) you shouldn’t be using type names (as opposed to variable names) repeatedly in a complex calculation… if you are you are doing something wrong… and; 3) type aliases exist, so you can do using i = interval; if you really must.

I'm a native English speaker and have never heard of diapason, so probably don't use that word.  "limits" might work (only because it's obviously plural), or the mundane "min_max".
I think it's natural to use the same or similar words for one-dimensional bounds as for 2D or 3D - but I don't see that as necessarily causing extra confusion given that we already use them across those two geometries, and sometimes for higher dimensions, too.

Looking at the implementation, there are things you might want to change:

I would suggest constraining the template to only accept ordered types: i.e. template<std::totally_ordered T=float>.  Consider double as a more natural default than float in C++.

Possibly better as a class with a constructor that enforces a variant min <= max.

The addition in center() can overflow the type T¹ - but we have std::midpoint() as a safe alternative.  This function probably only makes sense for numeric types rather than all ordered types, so perhaps it should be constrained too.  After all, what's the midpoint of two strings?



¹ Overflow might just lead to a wrong result, but for signed integer types, it's Undefined Behaviour!

Thank you for the input. I am concerned with 'limits' because of two reasons which fall into one: C++ std library already has std::limits which could lead to confusion during discussions and which is more important it gives people some kind of sense/assumption that limits in C++ are for the border values not for the data set, but for the types themselves (like min(), max(), lowest(), etc.). So this is language-term-intersection-risky and still risky for misunderstanding.

It is worked always for me for defined floats (not for NaNs, -inf, etc). What could be the trap? In which case except this non-values, float could show its not strongly-ordered behavior? Can you show an example, please?

I am not sure about the min <= max invariant, since before I start search for a range in a loop of values, often I have to initialize in exactly in the opposite way: range<float> range = { std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() }; so that I can find max and min values from the array of values in the loop later. This could be solved with 'bool valid()' method which gives true if min <= max (it is not always possible to initialize them by the first element of the set, since the set could miss it).

I just mean that writing template<std::totally_ordered T> might prevent instantiation with floating-point types.  But I've just tried that and it seems okay.

Fair enough about the invariant - that was a use case we weren't shown.

On the float my point is that I use this type mostly with float variables and if they could cause any issues I would be happy to know about it beforehand. I can't just forbid float usage, since range<float> is very valuable for me.
